# What causes the constant messages "the file was changed on disk; reload, ignore?"

Tags: nas, editing, file-properties

#### The issue

While (in this case) editing a `.css` file in Bluefish, I am switching to the browser to reload the page and test the result. After that, I switch *back* to the `.css` file, and get the message that "the (`.css`) file was edited on disk".

[image]

I am pretty sure it wasn't me, editing the file from another application. 
This is *constantly* happening, *if* it happens, which is not always. When it starts, it is unstopable.

#### No Bluefish issue

Since it is not only with Bluefish, but similarly when writing e.g. a bash script in `gedit`, the "edit", must be real. In the file nothing is actually changed however.

#### Note

I am editing the files on a NAS, locally linked on my desktop.

Comment: Maybe because the access time changed in the files stats, try a `stat filename` if this causes the same behavior.

Comment: @Videonauth yeah, I am pretty sure that happens, but what is it caused by?

Comment: When the file is shown on server it gets loaded and therefore the access time possibly changed, this will cause a change in the files checksum, and on the long run makes your editor believe the file has changed.

Comment: @Videonauth Waitwait you might have a point there, I moved the files to a NAS, linked on my desktop. will try to copy it locally, see if that havppens then as well...

Comment: @Videonauth and it doesn't!! If you produce an answer, I'll accept :) great.

Comment: uuuuhhmm... a downvote? please explain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As we discussed in comments and found out that the files are on a NAS, testing the files does in fact read them and causes a change in their access time stat as you can see with:

```
stat <filename>
```

As this is part of the file itself it therefore changes the files checksum and makes your editor believe that the file has been changed.

Comment: The solution is to reconfigure the FS to not take metadata-access as writing, or to use an arg to `stat` that doesn't clobber on read.

Comment: Sorry, how is the `stat` command exaclty telling us about the issue? Should one see that the Access field has a very recent date? Thanks!

Comment: I think the ideas is when you observe the issue, if you then look at stat for the file, you will verify there is a new access time that coincides with the error. So @cat, how do you reconfigure the FS not to take metadata-access as writing?